# could not access the attributes of objects while in implementing thymeleaf in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i cant seem to access the attributes of the objects passed to the html filein thymeleaf. I am building a spring REST Web application.

CODE IN CONTROLLER

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/home/books"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView books()
    {
        ModelAndView modelAndView=new ModelAndView();
        Book book =new Book("name","author","id","54");
        //book.addBook(book("name","author","id","54"));
        List<Book> AllBook =bookService.getAllBooks();
        AllBook.add(book);
        modelAndView.addObject("books",AllBook);
        modelAndView.setViewName("books");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

books.html file in my template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorate="~{default}">
    <head>
        <title>Books</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <tr th:each="book: ${books}">
            <h1> <td th:text="${book.author}" /></h1>
            <td th:text="${book.name}" />
        </tr>
    </body>
</html>
```

POJO class

```
Public class Book implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private String price;
    private int quantity;

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Book(String name, String author, String id, String price) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public Book()
    {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }    
}
```

thee web page dosent show the values of book.author or book.name. IT should show 
name , author.The page itself is responding but no values are shown. 
This error is shown
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "book.name" (template: "books" - line 11, col 9)

Did i make any mistakes using thymeleaf?
please help

Comment: modelAndView.setViewName("book");

Comment: are you sure your html file name is 'book.html' not 'books.html'?

Comment: sorry its books.html, thank you for correcting me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Define public `setters` and `getters` in your `POJO`

```
@Entity
public class Book{
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String author;



    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    private String price;
    private int quantity;

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Book() {

    }
    public Book(String id, String name, String author, String price, int quantity) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }



}
```

## books.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorate="~{default}">
<head>
<title>Books</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr th:each="book: ${books}">
            <h1>
                <td th:text="${book.author}"></td>
            </h1>
            <td th:text="${book.name}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

## Bookrepository

```
public interface Bookrepository extends JpaRepository<Book, String>{    

}
```

## BookService

```
public interface BookService {

    public List<Book> getALlBooks();

    public void addBook(Book book);
}
```

## BookService Implementation

```
@Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    @Autowired
    Bookrepository bookrepository;

    @Override
    public List<Book> getALlBooks() {

        return bookrepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void addBook(Book book) {

        bookrepository.save(book);
    }

}
```

## Your Controller

```
@Controller("/")
public class BooksController{

    @Autowired
    BookService bookService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "home/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView books() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        Book book = new Book("id", "name1", "author1", "54", 5);
        Book book2 = new Book("id 2", "name2", "author2", "54", 4);

        bookService.addBook(book);
        bookService.addBook(book2);

        List<Book> AllBook = bookService.getALlBooks();


        // Check here if list is empty and throw an exception

        modelAndView.addObject("books", AllBook);
        modelAndView.setViewName("books");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

## Explanation

Your first problem is caused because you didn't define `setters` and `getter`. You had private fields with no way to access them outside your class.

You second problem is caused because you pass empty list. Make sure to check for your variables before passing them. A simple `logger` won't do you anything bad. Most of the time, it comes very handy.

Comment: Getter/Settings are missing, correct. But I wouldn't say "Everything you did was correct" to the TO. Have a look at these <tr>-Elements without a table and a <h1>-Element containing a <td>-Element.

Comment: i added them but it still doesnt work. COuld you help me to find the problem.

Comment: I am gonna update update my answer to fully working example.

Comment: It shows this error
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "book.name" (template: "books" - line 11, col 9)

Comment: because you passed an empty list. Wait for a full example

Comment: @Flocke Feel free to edit the answer if you find something unmeaningful

Comment: @plp no problem. If the answer helped you make it as valid

Answer (score 0):

are you sure your html file name is 'book.html' not 'books.html'?

If it is book.html then you should set view name `modelAndView.setViewName("book");`

otherwise change file name to books.html and set view as `modelAndView.setViewName("books");`

Comment: the name is books.html, im sorry for the mistake. It dosent run

Comment: Alien could u please tell me what is wrong with the code.

Comment: attach pojo class too...just want to check constructor.

Comment: ive attached the POJO class but i think the problem is how i used thymeleaf im not very good at it